# cycle units measurement through hotkey is it possible?

Tags: workflow, units

i find imperial is much easy or convenient to setup with camera distance from 
object a to b and eye level height

i want to set a hotkey that cycle through units ( metric , imperial ) 
hitting same hotkey instead of manually going to tab and click the desired units button

i tried to use wm.context_toggle_enum and type the following attributes but gives error
**context.scene.system , scene.system , UnitSettings.system , data.scene , data.scene.system**
or do i need a custom .py script in order to achieve the cycling of metric and imperial units

thank you for answer

[image]

Comment: Can't you just right-click on the measurement setting in the Properties panel and assign a hotkey?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The path to use for the context Attribute is

```
scene.unit_settings.system
```

Where you find a class name of `UnitSettings` is shown with it's name in [CamelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase), you will often find a corresponding property that represents it will use the form `unit_settings` with all lowercase and underscore separating words.